# Java - Generate a web form using CICS API

Tags: java, web-services, cics

I have a task which  needs to place a random 8-digit numeric token, rtok, in a
container of the process (call it TOKEN) and notify user a URL where they can go to and tick an option. The URL should be of the form
https://zeuszos.edu.ihost.com:8005/afcheck/customer/she00nn?proc=AFCnnnnnnnn&token=rtok

The AFCnnnnnnnn, the nnnnnnnn is the random 8-digit numeric token. I have gone through [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/dfhpjd1.html) tutorial but it doesn't help much. Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a web app in CICS, then the CICS Liberty support, which enables the JEE6 & 7 Web profile and is a lot easier (and more standard) than using JCICS web and document classes, which is what the  old examples.web.Sample1 one uses. Liberty is supported in CICS since CICS TS V5.1 See this video for some high level info [Architecting Java solutions for CICS](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/crse0301.html?Open).

You can find information on developing a simple Liberty web app [here](https://developer.ibm.com/cics/2016/05/17/developing-liberty-applications-for-cics-part-2-writing-your-first-web-application/) on our CICS developer center and there is a tutorial here on using the [JCICS](https://developer.ibm.com/cics/2017/02/27/jcics-the-java-api-for-cics/) APIs

There is also a suite of sample Liberty apps [here](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Aliberty%20org%3Acicsdev&type=Repositories) on our CICSDev GitHub.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Hi Phil, you are actually the author of the article. I'm provided this http://upfile.mobi/IgWM0kaJP3f class to fetch the data. However everytime I tried to fetch data using `String CONTAINER = bts.get_process_container(PROCESS_NAME);` I always got an error. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.ibm.cics.server.Task.getCommonData()V`. How can I fix that?

Comment: ```java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.ibm.cics.server.Task.getCommonData() ``` signifies that your app failed to load the JCICS native library, when using the JCICS Task class. This sort of error usually means you are not running on a CICS enabled thread in the JVM. What type of CICS JVM server are you using, and how are you invoking your Java program?

Comment: I set Target Platform as CICS TS 5.1.

Comment: The Target Platform sets the plugins in your Eclipse that you are developing for, so that looks good. However, question is how is your Java class BTS.java invoked within the CICS runtime, is it via an EXEC CICS LINK or via a JNI call or?

Comment: I sorted it out anyway. I have to use the zosexplorer instead of the normal Eclipse.

Comment: OK good to hear it, you can either use standard Eclipse and install the CICS Explorer SDK into this, or you can use the z/OS Explorer which has everything built into it. The following [site](https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/products/downloads/) should give you access to whichever download you need.